# Image not render properly in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: html, css

I have used Banner image in HTML .

In Outlook the banner image get shrink and display below the actual size.
Example :
 Actual size : width=650px
 In Outlook : width=320px

While view the same HTML page with header banner in all other browser it display with actual size (width:650px)

Help me on this rendering issues.

I need to add any css properties.

Comment: Please go through..http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turns out that if you load the image as an attachment (eg. you paste from a browser to an email client), it has a 320px limit. Try to send the html directly from API.